File downloaded using ytdl-core is not complete when sent to client
I'm working on a Node.js application that downloads audio files from YouTube using the ytdl-core library and then sends them to clients for download.I'm facing this issue where the downloaded file is incomplete when it is sent to the client.
const audioStream = fs.createWriteStream(outputPath);
audio.pipe(audioStream, { end: false });

audio.on("progress", (_, downloaded, total) => {
  const percent = ((downloaded / total) * 100).toFixed(2);
  console.log(percent);
  io.emit("progress", percent);
});

audio.on("end", () => {
  console.log("Download complete");
  res.send(outputPath);
});

audio.on("error", (err) => {
  console.error("Error downloading audio:", err);
  res.status(500).json({ error: "Error downloading audio" });
});


I have tried reading the stream and piping the response to client, it works but what happens is the download dialog box appears very late and when i click on save the download is already complete. i want the file to start downloading on the clients browser.
